# How to assign ids to sets of coordinates? -python

Tags: python, geopandas

I am working with a `GeoDataFrame (gdf)` containing a road network (Lines) that looks like the following:

```py
    id_road speed   geometry
0   1       50.00   LINESTRING (a_lon a_lat, b_lon b_lat)
1   2       50.00   LINESTRING (b_lon b_lat, c_lon c_lat)
2   3       48.00   LINESTRING (b_lon b_lat, e_lon e_lat)
3   4       50.00   LINESTRING (c_lon c_lat, d_lon d_lat)
4   5       51.00   LINESTRING (c_lon c_lat, f_lon f_lat)
...
```

And here is a simplified drawing of the network:

[image]

I would like to add to `gdf` a set of two ids. If we take the example given in the drawing above:

- The first id would be the beginning of the road (eg. for Road_1, this id would be `begin_road` and it would equal to 1).
- The second id would be the end of the road (eg. for Road_1 `end_road` = 2).

But then I would like `end_road` of Road_1 to be `begin_road` of Road_2.

I thought about associating the coordinates values with an id value so that, in `gdf` I would get:

- (a_lon, a_lat) = 1
- (b_lon, b_lat) = 2
- (c_lon, c_lat) = 3
- (d_lon, d_lat) = 4
- (e_lon, e_lat) = 5
- (f_lon, f_lat) = 6

```py
    id_road speed   begin_road end_road geometry
0   1       50.00   1          2        LINESTRING (a_lon a_lat, b_lon b_lat)
1   2       50.00   2          3        LINESTRING (b_lon b_lat, c_lon c_lat)
2   3       48.00   2          5        LINESTRING (b_lon b_lat, e_lon e_lat)
3   4       50.00   3          4        LINESTRING (c_lon c_lat, d_lon d_lat)
4   5       51.00   3          6        LINESTRING (c_lon c_lat, f_lon f_lat)
...
```

I am not sure how to manage to code this and if this method would be the most adequate one for what I am looking to do. Any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a scrappy implementation, but let me know if it helps:

To begin you likely need some way of transforming coordinate pairs to a list of pairs from which you can index:

```
coordinate_pairs = df['geometry'].apply(lambda g: [g.coords[0], g.coords[-1]])
coordinates = [p for pair in coordinate_pairs for p in pair]
coordinates_to_index = {tuple(coordinates[i]): i for i in range(len(coordinates))}
```

After which you can retrieve the indices to create the new columns:

```
df['begin_road'] = df['geometry'].apply(lambda g: coordinates_to_index.get(g.coords[0]))
df['end_road'] = df['geometry'].apply(lambda g: coordinates_to_index.get(g.coords[-1]))
```

Comment: Wow this helped a lot thank you very much! It's actually quite clear!